# Check if required fileds are selected in a selects "row"

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have multiple selects in a form, and I need to check with jQuery that at least all required fields (`required="true"`) are selected.

Something like this:

```
<select class="check" name="first">
    <option value="some" required="true">Some required</option>
    <option value="other">Other Value</option>
    <option value="few" required="true">Few required</option>
</select>
<select class="check" name="second">
    <option value="some" required="true">Some required</option>
    <option value="other">Other Value</option>
    <option value="few" required="true">Few required</option>
</select>
<select class="check" name="third">
    <option value="some" required="true">Some required</option>
    <option value="other">Other Value</option>
    <option value="few" required="true">Few required</option>
</select>
<select name="other">
    <option value="some" required="true">Some required</option>
    <option value="other">Other Value</option>
    <option value="few" required="true">Few required</option>
</select>
```

I need to check all the select elements whose class contains `.check` and make sure that all required fields are assigned.

I was thinking of proceeding as follows.

1. Make an array of all required values:

   ```
   var requiredFields = [];
   $('option:selected', this).attr('required').each(function(){
       requiredFields.push($(this).val());
   })
   ```
2. Make an array of all the selected values:

   ```
   var valuesSelected = [];
   $('.check').each(function(){
       valuesSelected.push($(this).val());
   })
   ```
3. Check if the required fields are in the selected values array, if not do something:

   ```
   for(i=0;i<requiredFields;i++){
       if(jQuery.inArray(requiredFields[i], valuesSelected)==-1){
            var error += 'Please select '+requiredFields[i];
       }
   }
   ```
4. Show the error message, or if empty does something:

   ```
   if(error!=''){
       alert(error); // just for testing
   } else {
        // have fun
   }
   ```

I've put up a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vNcU/1/) to test it, but it seems I must be doing something wrong, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a way to do it with maps
http://jsfiddle.net/4vNcU/4/

```
$(document).on('click', '.check-select', function () {
var error = $(".check").find("option:selected").map(collectErrors);
for (var i = 0; i < error.length; i++) {
    alert(error[i]);
}
});

function collectErrors() {
    if ($(this).attr("required") == undefined) {
       var $parent = $(this).parent();
       return "Please select one of the folowing:" + 
       findRequired($parent) + 
       " For the select box " + $parent.attr("name");
    }
}

function findRequired($parent) {
    return $parent.find("option[required=true]").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).toArray().join()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't create arrays or add an element to an array like that in javascript.

Replace

```
var requiredFields = array();
```

with

```
var requiredFields = [];
```

and

```
requiredFields[]=$(this).val();
```

with

```
requiredFields.push($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I had many things done wrong:

```
    var requiredFields = [];
    $(form).find('option[required]').each(function(){
        if(jQuery.inArray($(this).html(), requiredFields)==-1){
            requiredFields.push($(this).html());
        }
    })
    var valuesSelected = [];
    $(form).find('option:selected').each(function(){
        valuesSelected.push($(this).html());
    })
    for(i=0;i<requiredFields.length;i++){
        if(jQuery.inArray(requiredFields[i], valuesSelected)==-1){
             var msgErr2 = msgErr2 + 'Please select '+requiredFields[i]+'<br>';
        }
    }
```

This one works just fine, hope it helps someone!